# How can I close all (plone) sessions opened by a user except the current one?

Tags: session, plone, privacy

Let's suppose I'd opened two or more user sessions on two or more devices (same user with not admin privileges).

At the current session, if I log out, it means all others sessions will also close? If not, is there a way to do this by an URL request?

something like this:

1. User call a method, ex: `[plone-site]/close-all-sessions-except-this`;
2. Results on: all user sessions, opened on the others devices are closed.

Would be better if this method were native in plone.

gmail has this [feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en). I think it's an important security and privacy issue.

Comment: I've done a test: open two user sessions from a site (plone 4.3) in two different machines. Logging out from one doesn't close the session from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice feature request, would you mind [opening an issue?](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/new) AFAIK Plone doesn't include that by default.

When you log out of one session Plone will close all sessions for that browser AND site URL, because the session is stored in a cookie set to site's domain. However Plone won't log you out from other browsers/devices, nor in the edge case you're accessing the site by IP, if that's available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and request channel, @Davi. I'm think about the way to request it: a single method or something more sophisticated as a user session manager screen. This screen could be one more item in useractions view. Just a humble user opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you are asking, but if you want to automatically logout all authenticated users (not only *one* user) you can:

- Go to ZMI
- Enter inside `acl_users`
- Select the `session` plugin
- In the "Invalidate all session identifiers" section click the "Clear secrets" button.

As you can read there:

> By clicking the button below you clear all secrets used to validate
>   sessions. This will immediately log out all users who use session
>   authentication and require them to log in again.

Comment: I want just avoid ZMI. In gmail page, on right-down corner, there's a link named **_details_**. Press this link and will open a new windows that shows all opened sessions, there has a button I can close them all opened sessions except the current. So, I'm asking if there's something similar in plone but avoiding ZMI. I just want to create a link to the (not admin) user. Is it clear now?

Comment: Davi Lima has answered, there's not this feature, @keul :(. Anyway thanks for one more plone/zope tip.